# Adding new field in article manager in frontend of Joomla 3.0

Tags: forms, joomla3.0

I am trying to add new field in new article in frontend of joomla as described here: http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_the_article_component

But the fields are not shown on the form. Can anybody explain me the reason?

Below is my code written in plugin file:

```
function onContentPrepareForm($form, $data)
{
    if (!($form instanceof JForm))
    {
        $this->_subject->setError('JERROR_NOT_A_FORM');
        return false;
    }

    // Add the extra fields to the form.
    // need a seperate directory for the installer not to consider the XML a package when "discovering"
    JForm::addFormPath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/rating');
    $form->loadFile('rating', false);
    return true;
}
```

The one thing I observed is that, in my com_content folder inside component, the fixed code is written and that is the reason, why my fields are not visible. Is it ok if I change the file: \components\com_content\views\form\tmpl

Comment: Assuming you aren't using the code from the doc verbatim, you should post your plugin code. It is most likely that your plugin isn't registered properly. Is it installed? Enabled? I'd do a var_dump or exit statement right in the plugin code just to make sure it is even being run.

Comment: @DavidFritsch I added my code segment, if you can help!

Comment: @DavidFritsch my plugin is installed, enabled and it is being executed, I have tested it using die().

Comment: Is that *all* the code in the plugin file?

Comment: @DavidFritsch yes, the code I have copied in my question is from my plugin file, rating.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that there is another bug in the tutorial, at least concerning my version of Joomla which is 2.5.14.

In you /rating/rating.xml (**the form description, not the manifest**) you need to change "

`<fields name="rating">`

to

`<fields name="attribs">`

There is something special about using the "attribs" name in order for the plugin to work.

Comment: Thanks, this was useful.  I was trying to get it to work in Joomla 3.1, and this fixed the admin edit screen, making the fields show up.  Still not seeing the fields in the front-end editing and front-end viewing.

Comment: @Joel , it works in backend but not yet in frontend. Please do the needful if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the conversation in the comments above, I think you are subject to a poorly built tutorial. Well the document never states this, you actually have to wrap this function in a class for the CMS to call the function properly.

Even without the class wrapper, the file will be loaded into the CMS, so if you put a `die` or `exit` statement outside of the function, you should see it work. If you put it in the function, it won't be called, because your function will never be called.

You can download the full plugin from the tutorial that you reference at the bottom of the tutorial or here: http://joomlacode.org/gf/download/trackeritem/28771/75013/plg_content_rating-2.5.0.zip. If you look at this, you will see the extra pieces that are needed for this to actually function. I'm including it as well below.

Any of the other functions would also have to go in the class. Also, if you have changed the name of the plugin at all, the class name would also need to be updated. This can be pretty tricky, since the naming convention is very strict and requires both the plugin name (`rating`) and the plugin group (`content`) to be correct.

Code:

```
class plgContentRating extends JPlugin
{
    function onContentPrepareForm($form, $data)
    {
        if (!($form instanceof JForm))
        {
            $this->_subject->setError('JERROR_NOT_A_FORM');
            return false;
        }

        // Add the extra fields to the form.
        // need a seperate directory for the installer not to consider the XML a package     when "discovering"
        JForm::addFormPath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/rating');
        if (!$form->loadFile('rating', false)) {
            die('No Form');
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

*UPDATE: Ok, so it wasn't just the missing class, but I'm leaving that just in case it helps someone else.

I updated the above code to do a check on the loadFile to see if it is working.

Comment: Oh yes, ofcourse I have used a class! I am writting this inside a class only. When I am adding `die('testing');` then it is displayed. It means that the event is being called when I click on create a new article link. The problem is my fields are not being displayed which I have added in rating/rating/rating.xml file.

Comment: That's good. I could totally see how you could skip that from the tutorial and it really would still load the plugin file and run... The next step is probably to do some checking on LoadFile itself. It should return false if the file doesn't load. This should tell you whether it didn't find the file or if it isn't rendering.

Comment: But when I am writting `print_r($form)` inside this event, I am getting that fields for rating. So, my fields are loaded using LoadFile. But the problem is with the view file: \components\com_content\views\form\tmpl\edit.php